# dynamically creating list boxes in html

Tags: html, listbox, thymeleaf

I want to create a number of list boxes.But the number of listboxes I want to create is dynamic (I will only know at run time how many listboxes I require),So how do I code for it?

Answer (score 1):

As every loop in Thymeleaf `th:each` is your friend. So perhaps you need an additional div-Tag

`<div th:remove="tag" th:each= ...>
</div>`